# Post to CI Controller using JQueryAjax and Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Bootstrap Modal to take the user's input and submit it to a CI Controller for validation. I want to be able to return the results to the same modal (JSON) before the input is save to a database table. So far from the code, Firebug is telling me I have a TypeError : result is null. I'd like to get it to work. I am new to JQuery/Ajax Thank you for your help.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#createCardId').click('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //we'll want to move to page specific files later

    var email = $('input#email').val(); //from hidden field
    var location = $('input#location').val(); //from hidden field
    var card = $('#cardId').val(); //user's input

    $.ajax({
        url : "../edituser/addCardId",
        dataType : "json",
        type : 'POST',
        data : "email=" + email + "&location=" + location + "&CardId=" + card,
        success : function(result) {

            if (result.error) {
                $(".alert").fadeIn('slow');
                $("#error_message").html(result.message);

            } else {

                $(".alert").fadeIn('slow');
                $("#error_message").html(result.message);
                $('#new_item').modal('hide');
            }

        },
    });

});

});
```

**View-Modal Bootstrap**

```
        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade modal-admin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add Card ID</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!--############-->
        <!-- column left -->
        <div class="span6">
        <p>
            <?php 

            $location = $this->session->userdata('location');
            $email = $account->email;
            echo $location. '<br>'; 
            echo $email;


            if(validation_errors())
            {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
            }
            ?>


        <!--CARD ID -->
        <div id="error_message"></div> 
        <div class="control-group">
        <input id="email" type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        <input id="location" type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">    
        <label class="control-label">Card ID: <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="cardId" name="cardId" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!--END OF CARD ID-->
        </p>
        </div>
        <!--############ column left ends-->

        <!--############-->
        <!--column right-->

        <div class="span6">
            <p>Hello <?php echo $location; ?></p>
        </div>
        <!--############ column right ends-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="createCardId" "data-dismiss=modal">Save changes</button>
        <!--<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary">-->

      </div>


      <!--############-->



    </div>
```

**CI Controler**

```
public function addCardId()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('CardId', 'Card Id', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[6]|is_unique[accounts.CardId]');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $location = $this->input->post('location');
     $result = array();

     if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
    {

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['message'] = validation_errors();

         } else {

            $result['error'] = TRUE;
            $result['message'] = 'The Card ID has been saved';           

            //Model will load here to add Card ID to the database.               
            redirect('admin/editaccount/search_account', 'refresh');
        }  


        $json = json_encode($result);
        die($json);
    }
    else
    {

        redirect('../searchaccount/showresults', 'refresh');
    }

}
```

**Thank you for your help!!**

Comment: it was my silly mistake about the `,`.

Comment: I am using Firebug to track errors. Under POST: I get the variables I am posting so I think that's right. Also, Under Response I get the folowing: 
    {"error":true,"message":"<div class='alert alert-error'><\/div>"}{"error":true,"message":"<div class='alert alert-error'><\/div>"}

Comment: Anyways, why you are using in both condition `TRUE` ?

Comment: Can you check `console.log(result)` at the first line of your success ?

Comment: 1. To start with, I do not think my controller is running the validation.

Comment: 2. What changes do you suggest ? console.log(result) is not coming up on the screen nor the console.

Comment: Then it's not executing in the `if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
    {` instead it's going to `else` and which is a redirect.

Comment: Confusing! Can you run the script without ajax, just `disable/comment the ajax` and try to submit the form normally and see what you get.

Comment: it is not going to the else statement. Firebug is telling me I have an error at if (result.error) line.. 
Any idea? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally accomplished what I needed. Here is the code.

**view**

```
<!-- model content -->    
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
        <div class="modal-header">
              <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
              <h3>Card ID</h3>
        </div>
    <div>
        <form class="contact">

             <div class="modal-body">
                 <ul class="nav nav-list">
           <input id="email" type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
           <input id="location" type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">
           <label>Please enter a valid Card ID:</label>
           <input id="CardId" type="input" name="CardId"  maxlength="6"/>                
           </ul> 

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
         <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Save Changes</button>
      </div>
</div>  
<?php
                if ($account -> CardId) {
                    echo $account -> CardId;
                } else {

                    echo "<div id='thanks'><p><a data-toggle='modal' href='#form-content' class='label label-addvisit'>Card ID</a></p></div>";
                }
                ?>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {

$("button#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    url: "../edituser/addCardId",
    data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
                 $("#thanks").html(msg)
                $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
             },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
        }
          });
});
```

});

**Controller**

```
public function addCardId()
{

     if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
    {
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $location = $this->input->post('location');
        $CardId = $this->input->post('CardId');

        echo "<span class=\"label label-info\" >Card Id Assigned</span>";
    }


}
```

All I have left to do is run some validations in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller :

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $result['error'] = true;
        $result['message'] = validation_errors();

     } else {
        $result['error'] = FALSE; //TRUE; should be FALSE
        $result['message'] = 'The Card ID has been saved';           

        // Model will load here to add Card ID to the database.
        // Why redirect this AJAX request?
        // redirect('admin/editaccount/search_account', 'refresh');
    }  

    $json = json_encode($result);
    die($json);
}
```

Try outputting the `result` value to the console :

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success : function(result) {
        // Add this line
        console.log(result);
        if (result.error) {
            $(".alert").fadeIn('slow');
            $("#error_message").html(result.message);

        } else {
            $(".alert").fadeIn('slow');
            $("#error_message").html(result.message);
            $('#new_item').modal('hide');
        }

    },
});
```

Comment: I am using XSS_clean in the validation so yeah I changed the config global xss filtering to TRUE. Is this what you meant? Although How would I check the server>? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Could you use firebug network monitoring feature to examine HTTP headers sent and response when you click on the `#createCardId` button? Tell us what you get please.

Comment: I am using Firebug to track errors. Under POST: I get the variables I am posting so I think that's right. Also, Under Response I get the folowing: {"error":true,"message":"<div class='alert alert-error'><\/div>"}{"error":true,"message":"<div class='alert alert-error'><\/div>"}

Comment: Do you get anything when you insert `console.log(result);` before `if (result.error)` ?

Comment: Yes, I get the else statement from my controller as: {error: true, message: "the card has been saved" }

Comment: If you get the else statement from your controller then this is working no?

Comment: My controller wasn't running any validation. The $result variable was basically giving me the wrong validation. I still need to learn JSON and how to manipulate the objects returned.